# array_positions() with comparison, not equality

Tags: postgresql

Postgres has the function array_positions:

```
array_positions(ARRAY[1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1], 1);
-> {1,4,8}
```

Which checks for equality of the second argument. I can't find anywhere if it has a function for comparison. E.g. (element in array > 1) which would return `{2, 3, 5, 6, 7}` in this example.

Does postgres have an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: If you really need to do that on a regular basis, consider properly normalizing your data model. [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) "*Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign.*"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT position
FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1]) WITH ORDINALITY a(element, position)
WHERE element > 1
```